# "Advantage" in the context of animacy

Tags: word-usage

Is it ok to say "my [or his or her] **advantages**"?  Or should  *advantage* be used only for non-sentient subjects, for instance, "advantages and disadvantages of a company"?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really idiomatic to speak of *the advantages of a **company*** either. Usually we speak of the advantages of *[using] **a method*** when we mean *benefits*. If we're talking about the actual attributes of something/someone that are advantageous in some context, we tend to call them *assets, strengths, strong points*.

Comment: thx, it makes sense. And I'll correct a doc using a more natural word.

Comment: It really does depend on the exact context, which you haven't given. But I'm assuming you mean something like *the advantages **of hiring** me* (to a prospective employer), rather than *my advantages **over other candidates** [applying for the same job]*. If the advantage associated with a person is for *someone else's **benefit***, that's probably the best word to use.

Comment: I think it's common to say, "Bill's advantages are strength and speed", or "Foobar Corporation's advantages are high volume and access to markets."

Answer (score 1):

It’s OK to speak of practically any entity, animate or inanimate, corporate or individual, physical or mental, as possessing or offering an advantage.

But when you start playing with prepositions you have to be careful.

Keep in mind that five distinct entities are involved when you speak of advantages.

- First, there is the Benefactor—the entity which provides the advantage. We usually speak of this with ***of***: the advantage ***of*** speed, the advantage ***of*** access to markets, the advantage ***of*** wealth.
- Second, there is the Beneficiary—the entity which enjoys or wields the advantage. We usually speak of this with ***to***: the advantage of speed ***to*** a predator, the advantage of access to markets ***to*** an enterprise, the advantage of wealth ***to*** a student.

  Note that either of these first two may be expressed with the genitive: speed's advantage, or the predator's advantage.
- Third, there is the Domain—the entity within which the advantage obtains. We usually speak of this with ***in***: the advantage of speed  ***in*** hunting, the advantage of access to markets ***in*** increasing sales, the advantage of wealth ***in*** getting a good education.
- And fourth and fifth, there are the Rivals—the entities with respect to which an advantage is asserted. Rivals are of two sorts, rivals to the Benefactors or rivals to the Beneficiaries: either one advantage is superior to others, or one competitor is superior to others by virtue of enjoying that advantage. We usually speak of this with ***over***: the advantage of speed ***over*** strength in hunting, the advantage students from rich families have ***over*** students from poor families.